# Refresh div onClick

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm using the awesome CodaSlider within wordpress to add a tabbed function to a page of mine but have run into a bit of a wall.

The CodaSlider uses a script that looks at the current content and defines a height automatically, however, I've got the option to open/close a div inside the slider to show more content but because the slider has already been defined a height, it won't automatically update.

My thoughts were to add a piece of JQuery that refresh the slider's div thus showing the new content without having to reload the entire page all the time.

So far this is what I have:

```
<div class="video-centre">
  <div class="video-title"> <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/video-propertiesforsale.jpg" alt="properties for sale" /> </div>
    <div class="video-point"> <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/video-point.jpg" alt="video pointer" /> </div>
    <div class="video-thumb">
      <div class="coda-slider" id="slider-id">
        <div>
          <h2 class="title"><span>Crouch End</span></h2>
          <?php the_field('crouch_end'); ?>
            <p class="video-more2"><a href="javascript:animatedcollapse.show(['expandable-2'])" id="refresh">View More</a></p>
            <div id="expandable-2">
            <?php the_field('properties_for_sale_hidden'); ?>
            <p class="video-close2"><a href="javascript:animatedcollapse.hide(['expandable-2'])" id="refresh">Close</a></p>
         </div>
        </div>





<script>
var $r = jQuery.noConflict();
    $r(function() {
      $r("#refresh").click(function(evt) {
         $r(".panel").load("index.php")
         evt.preventDefault();
      })
    })
</script>
```

The wall I've hit is that the script loads the entire page rather than the actual content it's supposed to and I can't seem to get it to do what I want.

I hope the above is understandable, it sounded alright in my head :S

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, `.load` is intended to load the entire contents of a page. You can run `.load`, then go through the children to get what you want:

```
var div = $('<div/>').load('index.php');
$('.panel').replaceWith(div.find('.panel'));
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, shall i replace the line:
$r(".panel").load("index.php")
with your suggestion?

Comment: Yes, but use your noConflict variable instead of $

Comment: Hmmmm....I've just had a good test but it's not loading any content now and collapses the other parent divs. I thought it might be looking at the wrong div to refresh but changing that has no effect either.

Comment: the find needs to actually find the element you want to replace it. I assumed that you wanted to replace that div with the same div from a different page, if not, it will fail.

Comment: I see, what happens if I just want to refresh the div on the same page rather than populate it from a different page?

Comment: I think my question might of been a bit confusing or the script I currently had was incorrect. 

All I wanted to do was to refresh the div on the page so it notices that extra content has been added thus the javascript updating the height automatically. 

I'm not looking to load specific content from another page.